# How to replace string in Prometheus query?

Tags: regex, prometheus, grafana

To monitor the state of some systemd-services, we got a State-timeline visualisation in Grafana looking like this:

[Picture of our current grafana visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfzyo.png)

The **query** for this is:

```
sum(node_systemd_unit_state{instance=~"^.*$",state="failed"}) by (name, state) > 0
```

and it outputs the timeline graph, where each bar has a name looking like: `{name="certbot.service", state="failed"}`

Now, we want to **replace** every name **string** like `{name="certbot.service", state="failed"}` with only the name `certbot.service`.

I guess using some kind of RegEx like `(?<={name=")(.*)(?=",)` could help to match everything between `{name="` and `, state="failed}"`
Where `(?<={name=")` would match everythin before the name,
then `(.*)` is to replace every possible service-name and
the end `(?=",)` will cut everything begining with `",`

From googling, I already know, that there is the option "label replace" and also an option to configure something in the scraping settings?
But as I'm quite new to this topic, I didn't really understand how to use this functions or if they even fit my problem.

This is, what ChatGPT told me to try:

```
sum(node_systemd_unit_state{instance=~"^.*$",state="failed"}) by (name, state) > 0
| regex_replace(name, '(?<={name=")(.*)(?=",)', '$1')
```

But Grafana/Prometheus gives me a parsing error after the pipe-symbol

Can you give me some advise, where I could find further information about my problem or even tell me how to edit the query to just output the wanted name?

I already tried googling my problem. It seems, that there are some similar solutions to what could fit into my usecase but I don't have the knowledge to adapt it to my problem.
Of course I asked ChatGPT which couldn't help me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does not exactly match my original question, we found a solution, that would fit our needs.

See, in Grafana, when creating your visualisation, you got the option to edit your Legend.
We used the option *custom* and as string `{{label_name}}`.
By simply replacing that string with `{{name}}` we just got our service-name.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, which uses a capture group:

```
Find:    \{[^}]*\bname="(.*?)"[^}]*\}
Replace: $1
```

This pattern matches the `"name"` key anywhere inside the `{...}`.  It then captures the RHS in `$1` and replaces with this captured group.

Here is a working [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9uQOnz/1).